# Acts As Follower doesn't work on front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed Acts_as_follower. I used the methods from the documentation in my console so I've determined that user 1 follows user 2(using devise) in ActiveRecord, and on my front end in the users/show.html.erb page it shows the appropriate follow/unfollow portion of the button I've implemented. Unfortunately whenever I press the follow/unfollow button nothing changes or happens.

I'm thinking it's the routing but wondering if anybody has an idea of why nothing happens. I've confirmed the lack of action from my console.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   acts_as_followable
   acts_as_follower

   has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb=> "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

   has_many :articles
   has_many :comments
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :articles do
    member do
      put "Like",   to: "articles#upvote"
      put "Disike", to: "articles#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :users do
    get :follow
    get :unfollow
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user_articles = @user.articles
    end

    def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end
end
```

followers_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :js

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end
end
```

The button in users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="follow">
  <% if @user.followed_by?(current_user) %>
    <%= form_tag user_unfollow_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <center><%= button_tag 'unfollow', class: 'btn btn-primary' %></center>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_tag user_follow_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <center><%= button_tag 'follow', class: 'btn btn-success' %></center>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, this is indeed a routing issue. But you get an A for effort as the documentation doesn't discuss the front end, good on you for getting this far :)

Your routes should look more like:

```
resources :users do
  post :follow, to: "#followers#create"
  delete :unfollow, to: "followers#destroy"
end
```

Note that unfollow is calling destroy, so by convention it's delete, also by convention create should be post.

Given that, make sure your view will look like:

```
<div class="follow">
  <% if @user.followed_by?(current_user) %>
    <%= form_tag user_unfollow_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :delete, remote: true do %>
      <center><%= button_tag 'unfollow', class: 'btn btn-primary' %></center>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_tag user_follow_path(user_id: @user.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
      <center><%= button_tag 'follow', class: 'btn btn-success' %></center>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, I'm so glad.  can you accept the answer :)